# What is the difference between curl and wget below?

Tags: curl, wget

```
curl -o mnist.zip -L http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bx3/data/mnist.zip
```

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 58.96.175.173 port 7070: Connection refused

```
wget -o mnist.zip http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bx3/data/mnist.zip
```

successfully downloaded the mnist.zip.

What is the difference between curl and wget? why curl get refused?

**AFTER trying curl -v, I got messages below.**

`curl -o mnist.zip -L http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bx3/data/mnist.zip -v`

`*   Trying 58.96.175.173...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connect to 58.96.175.173 port 7070 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 58.96.175.173 port 7070: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 58.96.175.173 port 7070: Connection refused`

But I still have no idea why curl got refused.

```
shell> wget http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bx3/data/mnist.zip -d

DEBUG output created by Wget 1.15 on linux-gnu.
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2016-01-07 11:54:10--  http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bx3/data/mnist.zip
Connecting to 58.96.175.173:7070... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection refused.
Releasing 0x0000000002598870 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x0000000002598870.
```

`wget http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bx3/data/mnist.zip` 
got same refused as curl, But `wget http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bx3/data/mnist.zip -o mnist.zip` is good. Why? What is the differnce here?

Comment: Refer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/678404/what-is-the-difference-between-curl-and-wget

Comment: Do you use a proxy or are there any proxy variables set in your shell?

Comment: Thank you very much. When I remove `http_proxy`, everything becomes normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off trying to analyse both the requests

Use `curl -v` to analyse what are you doing wrong and you can analyse `wget` request by doing `wget -d` which shows what is happening with `wget`  request

Answer (score 1):

There are two major differences

1. On some systems, wget is not installed and only curl is available.
2. There is a major advantage of using wget. wget supports recursive download, while curl doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget's major strong side compared to curl is its ability to download recursively.

wget is command line only. There's no lib or anything, but curl features and is powered by libcurl.

curl supports FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP, TELNET, DICT, LDAP, LDAPS, FILE, POP3, IMAP, SMTP, RTMP and RTSP. wget supports HTTP, HTTPS and FTP.

curl builds and runs on more platforms than wget.

wget is part of the GNU project and all copyrights are assigned to FSF. 


The curl project is entirely stand-alone and independent with no organization parenting at all

curl offers upload and sending capabilities. wget only offers plain HTTP POST support.
```

This is from original source at http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html

Answer (score 0):

When I remove `http_proxy`, everything becomes normal. Thanks to [golimar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040245/golimar)